# Replicate contains string on row and move with specific result to new column Pandas python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to move a specific selected value of row to a new column with selected only value, what method that I need to do this? For example, I need to get only the value chosen that contains `'KOTA|KAB'` to a new column, from this case, what

I have some data:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                     A                       |
+---------------------------------------------+
| JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135 |
| JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274      |
| DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471   |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get specific value only and move to a new column, what I expect is look like this

```
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|                     A                       |           B          |
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135 | KOTA SURABAYA        |
| JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274      | KAB SIDOARJO         |
| DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471   | KAB BANYUWANGI       |
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

What I tried:

```
# initialize list of lists
testing = [['JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135'], 
           ['JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274'], 
           ['DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_test = pd.DataFrame(testing, columns=['A'])
  
for check in df_test['A']:
    test = re.sub(r'(\bKOTA\b)|(\bKAB\b)', '', check)
    print(test)
```

But the result above will remove the KOTA and KAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.sub` removed the text that is matched with the pattern from the string.

You can use a single capture group with `str.extract` for example:

```
testing = [['JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135'],
           ['JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274'],
           ['DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_test = pd.DataFrame(testing, columns=['A'])

df_test['B'] = df_test["A"].str.extract(r'\b((?:KOTA|KAB) \w+)')
print (df_test)
```

Output

```
                                             A               B
0  JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135   KOTA SURABAYA
1       JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274    KAB SIDOARJO
2    DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471  KAB BANYUWANGI
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I'm new to these pandas, well thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to extract KOTA/KAB and the following words (except digits), you can use:

```
df_test['B'] = df_test['A'].str.extract(r'(\b(?:KOTA|KAB)\b\D+\b)')
```

output:

```
                                             A                B
0  JL XXXX, KEC TAMBAKSARI KOTA SURABAYA 60135   KOTA SURABAYA 
1       JL XXXX, KEC PORONG KAB SIDOARJO 61274    KAB SIDOARJO 
2    DUSUN XXX, KEC SRONO KAB BANYUWANGI 68471  KAB BANYUWANGI
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird looks like we cross-posted, I'll remove it if you like

Comment: I was just going to say you can keep it and I will remove mine :-) Anyway, my +1 here